# Set Cron to run automatically without any event in magento

Tags: php, magento, cron

I want to fetch image via openkm server.. so i want to make Observer who run every two min

My `config.xml`  `FlyonitImage/Openkm/etc/config.xml`

```
<events>
             <openkm_image_send>
                   <observers>
                        <flyonitimage_openkm_model_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Flyonitimage_Openkm_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>sendimageopenkm</method>
                        </flyonitimage_openkm_model_observer>
                    </observers>
                </openkm_image_send>
            </events>

         <crontab>
                <jobs>
                    <openkm_image_send>
                        <schedule><cron_expr>*/2 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                        <run><model>Flyonitimage_Openkm_Model/observer::sendimageopenkm</model></run>
                    </openkm_image_send>
                </jobs>
            </crontab>
```

and `Observer.php` is `FlyonitImage/Openkm/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Flyonitimage_Openkm_Model_Observer
{
    public function sendimageopenkm()
    {
        //this collection get all users which have birthday on today
         Mage::log("nice to learn this ");
        return $this;
    }
}
```

but its not showing any log.. i will put fetchimage code after making log..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run element should have value like:

```
<run>
    <model>module/model::method</model>
</run>
```

In your case it should be:

```
<run>
    <model>openkm/observer::sendimageopenkm</model>
</run>
```

That should work only when you setup entry in crontab for the cron.php file located in the Magento root.

If you want to test before setting cron on OS, then hit magento-root/cron.php in browser. First time hit will create entry in your Magento cron schedule table.

Then after 2 min again hit the same URL. This time your job will be executed.

Thanks

Comment: i have make a changes but after run cron.php.... its not make any log.

i want to make cron job by using db how to process it...

Comment: Can you please verify once the cron_schedule table if it having a row with job_code = openkm_image_send? If row exists, check the status and scheduled_at of the row. If row not found, means something went wrong in configuration.

Comment: in my db all goes as pending....61
openkm_image_send
pending
NULL
2014-01-09 07:14:33
2014-01-09 07:32:00
NULL
NULL

Comment: Ok, it means your cron configuration is fine. Created date for your cron is 2014-01-09 07:14:33 and schedule date for execution is 2014-01-09 07:32:00. Run the cron.php after some time and you should get your logs now. That will also update the status in cron_schedule table as well.

Comment: thanks a lot....

can you help in one place more please... i have make a admin where i have set cron time... as 2min. 5 min, 30 min, 1day etc... now i want to make cron by using db... but in magento, confix.xml have crontab function... now how to run cron by sung db details...  ??

Comment: Ok. This is exactly what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446934/magento-cron-in-backend-configuration

Answer (score 0):

call the above sendimageopenkm() function by setting cron as

2 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q "ur path" 
(Here wget is internal browser in linux)

Comment: sorry i dont know magento. may be this can help u check it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644037/setting-up-cron-job-in-magento

Comment: actually i want to know i have call everything is correct way or anything wrong in this code???

Answer (score 0):

have you setup [magento-root]/cron.php properly? if yes then set cronjob run every 1 minute
or you can use 3rd part cronjob services such as:

```
- https://www.setcronjob.com/
- http://www.easycron.com/
- http://www.webcron.org/
```